# How to move scrollIntoView into angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

See my code snippets:

Directive `node`:

```
myModule.directive ('node', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        var node = scope.node;
        node.scrollTarget = element;
        // ...
    }
});
```

Function `scroll`

```
$scope.scroll = function (node) {
        $scope.showTree (node);
        $timeout (function () {
            node.scrollTarget[0].scrollIntoView ();
        }, 0, false);
    };
```

`scroll` is invoked per `ng-click=scroll(node)` and changes the model (`showTree`) as well as does some dom-manipulation (`scrollIntoView`).
It is said that dom-manipulations should be avoided in controllers. How can I write it better?